# How to publish an asp.net website on work network?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, host

I have been developing an ASP.NET application and I would like my work colleagues to give me feedback on it. I tried running it on IIS but because the database is located on a remote server, I am unable to host it properly?

Also, how can the colleagues access that site? my host name, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your connection string to your remote server (providing the DB accepts external requests).

Something like (assuming SQL)

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase; User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

It's an ugly hack, but you can do an if else statement, detect the DomainName ([Environment.UserDomainName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx)) and if matches the server then use one connection string, if it's your office's domain, then use that!

This means, you can still use your local IIS!

Comment: Well, you could then either Make them view it online (create a subdomain for testing which only shows those which match your company IP (if possible). Or, take a copy of the database so you can replicate it locally!

Comment: i thought about making a replication of the database locally - thanks a lot for that

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your web site on a local server which has IIS running on it. You can create your application on IIS and your colleagues can access your web site from the intranet via the name of the server easily.

Such as:

```
http://servername/yourprojectdirectory
```

And also the local server should have internet access for the remote database.

Comment: i don't have a local server - i would like to use my work laptop to host the website. the remote database is protected

Comment: Then you should configure your IIS and your laptop should have an IP address or alias accessible from the intranet.